# MSSQL and PHP 7 (32 bits system)

Tags: php-7

I am trying to find MSSQL for PHP 7 on a 32 system (Ubuntu, 32-bit) system. But when I try to follow the installation instruction (https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql) it seems that it is only for 64 bits systems?

As far as I can see the command `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list` returns `arch=amd64`.
Is it possible to get it in 32 bits/i386?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Looks like I can use `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sybase` as an backup solution if I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sybase
```

As I need UTF-8 encoding I had to change the version of the tds first:

```
sudo vim /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
```

Locate

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
;    tds version = VERSION_NUMBER
```

Set the current version number to be at least 7.0 and remove `;` from the beginning of the line. In order to set UTF-8 global add:

```
client charset = UTF-8
```

below the version you just set.

Restart php-fpm:

```
sudo service restart php7.0-fpm restart
```

As I use Nginx I restarted that as well just to be sure.
Now try adding a mssql connection:

```
$this->connection = new PDO('dblib:host='.$this->hostname.':'.
                            $port.';dbname='.$this->db_name.';charset=UTF-8'
                            ,$username, $password);
```

Note the `charset=UTF-8` part. This can be removed, but if you don't set the client charset in the config file this is another place were you can set it.
If you change the charset in the connection string it will override the global value.

Greetings!